# Why URL is distorted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please help solve the problem.

I use rails 5. I create simple site, whitch have follow navigation:

```
kalinin@kalinin ~/rails/test5 $ rails routes
         Prefix Verb URI Pattern                Controller#Action
     pages_home GET  /pages/home(.:format)      pages#home
    pages_about GET  /pages/about(.:format)     pages#about
pages_portfolio GET  /pages/portfolio(.:format) pages#portfolio
     pages_blog GET  /pages/blog(.:format)      pages#blog
  pages_contact GET  /pages/contact(.:format)   pages#contact
           root GET  /                          pages#home
```

home page have 2 paths:

```
http://localhost:3000/pages/home 
http://localhost:3000/
```

home page have js-slider. initialization code:

```
function clearText(field)
{
    if (field.defaultValue == field.value) field.value = '';
    else if (field.value == '') field.value = field.defaultValue;
}


var flashvars = {};
flashvars.xml_file = "photo_list.xml";
var params = {};
params.wmode = "transparent";
var attributes = {};
attributes.id = "slider";
swfobject.embedSWF("flash_slider.swf", "flash_grid_slider", "960", "350", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);


ddsmoothmenu.init({
  mainmenuid: "templatemo_menu", //menu DIV id
  orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
  classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
  //customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
  contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
})
```

Problem:
on path `http://localhost:3000/pages/home`
this slider is not displays. console output follow error message:

> GET http://localhost:3000/pages/photo_list.xml 404 (Not Found)

But on path `http://localhost:3000/` 
slider is displays without problems.

ps:
path `pages/photo_list.xml` is NOT exist. but path `public/photo_list.xml` is exist.

PageController:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    render layout: "home"
  end

  def about
  end

  def portfolio
    render layout: "portfolio"
  end

  def blog
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of this line:

`flashvars.xml_file = "photo_list.xml";`

That is going to be relative to the page you are on. So when you are on `http://localhost:3000/pages/home` it will try and load `http://localhost:3000/pages/photo_list.xml`. When you are on the homepage it will load the right file.

Change that line to this:

`flashvars.xml_file = "/photo_list.xml";`